# Is there any way we can convert RSA private key to x509 format?

Tags: rsa, pem

I have created private key and public key using below commands,

```
openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 1024

openssl req -new -x509 -key privatekey.pem -out publickey.cer -days 1825
```

Seems like both are in different format.
I need to convert **rsa privatekey.pem** to **x509** format.

Is there any way i can do that?

Comment: what do you mean by converting the private key to x509? do you want a file which contains both public and private key?

Comment: No, on running the first command, I get a private key which is in PKCS#1 format I believe. This key I want to use for encryption(as ideally both public key and private key can be used interchangeably) and the application I use needs key in x509 format. Also, I would like to specify that I am new to this arena and terminologies, so kindly enlighten me if my understanding and question are wrong.

Comment: public key, private key, certificate, x509, pkcs1, ... everything has a meaning and scenario where it's used. Stackoverflow is not an appropriate place to look for tutorial level information. You need to have some reasonable mastery of the basics first so that the question-and-answer format of stackoverflow can work.

Answer (score 10):

Probably, you meant a conversion of the RSA private key to the PKCS8 format.

From starting with:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

To:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If so, use the following command:

`openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in rsa.private.key -out pkcs8.private.key -nocrypt`